# Java using Generics

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface A like this:

```
public interface A{
    void myFirstMethod();
    void mySecondMethod();
}
```

And then I have this class:

```
public class MyClass{
    private List<? extends A> elements;

    public MyClass(){
        A obj = new A(){
            @Override
            public void myFirstMethod(){
              //SOME CODE
            }
            @Override
            public void mySecondMethod(){
              //SOME CODE
            }
        };
        elements.add(obj);
    }
}
```

I haven't use generics before (only things like `List<String>...`) so I can't see why this code doesn't compile. To be more precise, I get an error on the line `elements.add(obj);` that the method add is not applicable for these parameters.

EDIT:
I've changed the code and now the elements.add(obj) compiles fine, but I have another problem.

```
public class MyClass{
    private List<A> elements;

    public MyClass(List<A> elements){
        this.elements = elements;
        elements.add(obj);
    }
}
```

When I try to do this, it doesn't compile.

```
//A1 implements A
List<A1> list = new ArrayList<A1>();
MyClass(list);
```

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Imagine that you have two subclasses:

```
class A1 implements A {...}
class A2 implements A {...}
```

Then you could write:

```
List<? extends A> elements = new ArrayList<A1>(); // a list of A1
```

But then this should not compile:

```
elements.add(new A2()); //oops: an A2 is not an A1
```

For that reason, you can't add anything but `null` to a `List<? extends A>` because you don't know what actual generic type it is. In other words, `? extends A` means a specific, but unknown, subtype of `A` (or `A` itself).

In your case, a `List<A>` would probably do what you expect - you would be able to add some `A1`s and some `A2`s to it.

Comment: In other words: `?` means "unknown", not "any".

Comment: That's right; the notation `List<? extends A>` means that it's a `List` of some **specific** but **unknown** type. It does **not** mean that the list can contain a mixture of different types of objects that extend `A`; it means that the list contains objects of some definite type that extends `A`, but you don't know what the actual type is.

Comment: Just a follow up on it, I understood but just tried with something weird like, `List<? extends A> elements = new ArrayList<A>();` This line is working, but again when I try to add an object of A1, `elements.add(new A1());` it shows error. I can understand the error, but my question is why Java is allowing me at first place to write something like the first line.. `new ArrayList<A>();`

Comment: If you want to add something into generic collection of type A, use the `List<? super A>`.

Comment: @sakura Yes, that won't work, exactly because of what we're explaining. The compiler looks at the type of the variable `elements`, which is `List<? extends A>`. From that type alone, the compiler doesn't know what the exact type is of the elements in the list; it only knows that they are of some unknown type that extends `A`. Since it doesn't know what the type really is, you can't add anything to the list - because it's impossible for the compiler to tell whether what you try to put in is of a valid type or not. It does not matter that you initialize your variable with `new ArrayList<A>`.